# Ionic error: Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Running `$ ionic generate page pageName` results in the error:

```
Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects (CLI v2.2.2)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v8.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

This is in what started as an ionic v2 project, but I thought I had updated to ionic 3. After [following instructions](https://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/) to update to CLI v3, I still get this same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found a fix, but don't know if this is the actual answer. I needed to add the lines:

```
"typescript": true,
"v2": true
```

To the file `ionic.config.json`. Adding just the `"typescript": true,` was not enough.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you for the correct answer :)

Comment: amen :-). Worked for me as well. That was a weird one...haven't worked in Ionic since last year an now this all of a sudden