# Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects (CLI v2.2.2)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using IONIC project. Here I am trying to generate a new page. But not able to generate. I have attached the shown error. Kindly solve my question.

---

> Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,  it is highly
>   recommended to install/upgrade the following:
>
> Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g
>   cordova`

---

> Generators are only available for Ionic 2 projects (CLI v2.2.2)

**Your system information:**

```
Cordova CLI: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Ionic Framework Version: 3.9.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 3.2.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v8.12.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620882/ionic-error-generators-are-only-available-for-ionic-2-projects ?

Comment: No Dude, Now only I have check and tried. It's working fine. Thanks for your information. @CodeChanger